# If you don't cure a ham and just brine it, is it just considered a pork roast?

Tags: pork, ham

I brined a ham over night and then slow baked it. Then topped with an apricot honey glaze. It looked and tasted just like pork tenderloin and was white meat and not pink.

I know curing it gives it a salty taste and pink meat. Is what I made just a pork roast?

Answer (score 4):

Techincally, ham is the cut of meat (the rear leg of the pig)--so what you prepared was a fresh ham roast, or just a pork roast.  You happened to brine it preparation.

The term ham has also come to mean the cured pork product--or now, with so-calle turkey ham and whatnot on the market, similar cured meat products.  "Fresh ham" emphasizes that you have the non-cured cut.

The thing is:  as long as it was delicious and you enjoyed it, why worry? :-)

Comment: Thanks. It did come out well. I did a apricot, honey Jack Daniels and pineapple juice reduction and glazed the entire thing. OMG. The video came out great. It just wasn't pink. I might cure the meat next time to be a ham and not just pork.